# In Apple Enterprise Developer Program how can a developer generate an ipa that is not an team admin or agent

Tags: ios, xcode, build, enterprise

If I am on an iOS Enterprise Development team, but am not the agent or a team admin, is there any way I can produce an .ipa?

I need to archive and sign an app that users can test with. It will be fine if they have to register there UDID with our enterprise program, however what will not work is for our team agent to have to produce every beta build for testers, as they will be numerous. I am having trouble locating documentation on this scenario.

I also understand that there is Test Flight now, though I am unsure if that will suit our needs. Test Flight seems to be tightly coupled to Apple IDs. Our devices are shared amongst beta testers and as such are generally using one Apple ID...

Answer (score 0):

Your Agent/Admins should be setting up your provisioning profile with all of the devices that are applicable to testing within the Dev Portal. As long as you're signing your build with THAT provisioning profile all of those users/UDIDs will be able to install the app as a development build. It doesn't even need to be signed as Release or Distribution.

On another note the only difference between an Admin and a Member is permissions within the Dev Portal (cert approvals, provisioning profile creation, device registration, etc). Your Agent on the other hand has the distinct ability to Enterprise sign the Distribution build for mass-deployment.